# How do I search in Windows using the wildcard but only in the particular folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

When I use the wildcard for searching filetypes in Windows, how do I limit/restrict the search only to that particular folder. I want to restrict the results from folders within the folder am searching for.

In this example, I want results only from Desktop:

[image: Image here!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*.png -folder:"Desktop\*"
```

This will exclude the results from sub-folders of the Desktop folder.